# How to specify a directory when creating a File object?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, formatting, directory

This should be a really simple question but Google + my code isn't working out.

In Eclipse on Windows, I want my program to look inside a certain folder. The folder is directly inside the Project folder, on the same level as `.settings`, `bin`, `src`, etc. My folder is called `surveys`, and that's the one I want my `File` object to point at.

I don't want to specify the full path because I want this to run on both of my computers. Just the path immediately inside my Project.

I'm trying this code but it isn't working - `names[]` is coming back null. And yes I have some folders and test junk inside `surveys`.

```
File file = new File("/surveys");
    String[] names = file.list();

    for(String name : names)
    {
        if (new File("/surveys/" + name).isDirectory())
        {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure my mistake is within the String I'm passing to File, but I'm not sure what's wrong?

Comment: You need to give the absolute path.

Comment: Meaning the full path? There's no way to get the local path?
Then why is it when I create a File and write to it without specifying the path, it goes in the most broad folder it can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you didn't specify what platform you are running on.  On non-Windows, a leading slash signifies an absolute path.  Best to remove the leading slash.  Try this:

```
File file = new File("surveys");
System.out.println("user.dir=" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
System.out.println("file is at: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
String[] names = file.list();

for(String name : names)
{
    if (new File(file, name).isDirectory())
    {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Make sure the in your run configuration, the program is running from the projects directory (user.dir = `<projects>`)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your file is a directory before using file.list() on it, otherwise you will get a nasty NullPointerException.

```
File file = new File("surveys");
if (file.isDirectory()){
   ...
}
```

OR

```
if (names!=null){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the full path of your file with

`System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath())`

the picture would immediately become clear. File.getCanonicalPath gives you exactly the full path. Note that File normalizes the path, eg on Windows "c:/file" is converted to "C:\file".